# Monitor and control host in Docker container

Tags: docker, security, containers

I have a service in docker container needs to monitor CPU and disk usage of the host. It also needs to shut shutdown or reboot it's host. I know this is against the Docker/process isolation philosophy but I am looking for a common and secure way to do it

Comment: Interesting question. My guess is that you need some way of passing the required information from the host to the container. Run an Agent on the Host passing info to the Monitor-Master which runs in the Container. There are probably packages to do that.